# Taking PostgreSQL backup through PHP on Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get the backup of database through PHP.I am using Yii with PostgreSQL. I have tried the below code and is working on my local  Wamp server. But the below code is not working on the server which is Windows server 2008 R2. If I echo the result of join(' ', $dumpcmd) and copy it into command prompt, then it works.

```
public function actionBackup()
        {
            $path       = Yii::app()->basePath . '/data/backup/';
            $file=$path."data.backup";
            unlink($file);

            putenv("PGPASSWORD=postgres");
            $dumpcmd = array("pg_dump", "-i", "-U", escapeshellarg("postgres"), "-F", "c", "-b", "-v", "-f", escapeshellarg($file), escapeshellarg("mydb"));
            exec( join(' ', $dumpcmd), $cmdout, $cmdresult );
            putenv("PGPASSWORD");
            if ($cmdresult != 0)
            {
                # Handle error here...
                echo "Error: couldn't backup the data.";
                print_r($dumpcmd).'<br>';
                print_r($cmdout).'<br>';
                print_r($cmdresult).'<br>';
            }
             else {

                 $this->renderPartial('download_backup',array('file'=>$file));
             }
        }
```

print_r of variables is below

```
Array ( [0] => pg_dump [1] => -i [2] => -U [3] => "postgres" [4] => -F [5] => c [6] => -b [7] => -v [8] => -f [9] => "path_to/data/backup/data.backup" [10] => "mydb" ) Array ( ) 1
```

Comment: On this part -> "# Handle error here..." You should follow that comments directions

Comment: @Jesse         Please provide any example code

Comment: Thats what I want you to do :)

Comment: @Jesse I tried printing the values of $cmdout which is empty and $cmdresult which is 1

Comment: When I have an issue and not sure where it is, I print_r everything until I find the problem. More than those 2 vars declared in your script there.